# Message posting on friends wall without using Graph API

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

All Earlier i used below  code for posting  friends wall , it worked fine.

```
NSMutableDictionary  *postVariablesDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
 [postVariablesDictionary setObject:@"Please download Hollywood Burger <https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/doodlify/id578182515>" forKey:@"message"];
  [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/feed",[selectedFBfriendsArray objectAtIndex:i] ] parameters:postVariablesDictionary HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                  NSLog(@"result is %@",result);
                NSLog(@"error is %@",[error description]);
}
```

But Facebook deprecated posting on friend wall using Graph API
 refer this link

> **http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/14792062/posting-to-friends-wall-with-graph-api-via-feed-connection-failing-since-feb**.

i am able to post friend wall with using Feed dialogue

```
>     NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
>                                    @"401253773268767", @"app_id",
>                                    @"Reference Documentation", @"caption",
>                                    @"Using Dialogs to interact with users.", @"description",
>                                    @"1821531148",@"to",
>                                    nil];
>     [self.facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

But, i need post post on selected friends (multiple friends) wall.

Can u please help me someone ..

Thanks in advance.